# Regular expressions in search and replace

Tags: regex

I have inherited a couple of thousand lines of code with every array key string value missing its quote marks, for example `[input]` should read `['input']` otherwise my PHP (rightly) throws a right hissy fit when debugging.

I am trying a regular expression search and replace, I can find the parts OK, for instance `\[([a-z])\w+\]` will find `[input]` and ignore `['preview']`

But I can't work out how to do the replace.

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like [this](https://regex101.com/r/cD2zQ5/1)?

```
\[([^'\]]+)\]
```

Replaced with

```
['\1']
```

If it looks good, you can use `code generator` on the left to see the PHP regex code.

Comment: You can give a man a fish and he'll eat for a day, you show him regx101.com and he'll be eating regular expressions for life. 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\[(\w+)\]
```

With a replacement

```
['$1']
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG4yU3/1)**

Php code

```
$re = "/\\[(\\w+)\\]/"; 
$str = "[key]\n[key2]\n[key_asdf]"; 
$subst = "['$1']"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```